# Обрез строки средствами MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет. Сразу к делу.

Есть таблица с, предположим, товарами:

```
| id | name | category_id|    subcategory_id |
|----|------|------------|-------------------|
|  1 |  box |          1 |       {1},{2},{3} |
```

Коробка, с ID = 1 из категории номер 1. `{1},{2},{3}` сообщает о том, что `box` относится сразу к 3-м подкатегориям, ID которых я заключил в `{}`. При `SELECT` запросе я использую, например, `WHERE subcategory_id LIKE %{3}%` для того, что бы получить товары 3-й категории.

Довольно все просто. Но передо мной встал вопрос: как средствами MySQL без лишнего запроса и без использования PHP изменить эту строку `{1},{2},{3}` на, к примеру, `{1},{3}` тем самым удалив 2-ю категорию?

З.Ы. Вообще, на самом деле, речь идет вовсе не о товарах и категориях. Речь идет о выполнении заданий в браузерной игре. Я абсолютно осознаю что такой подход к реализации просто ужасен. Если у вас есть другие предложения по реализации, то жду вас в студию.
Смысл заключается в том, что Игрок покупает какую то запчасть. При совершении этого действия будет совершаться следующий запрос (на примере с товарами):

```
DELETE FROM `items` WHERE `category_id` = 1
```

Но, предположим, что задание купить не просто запчасть, а запасть у которой id = 3. То запрос будет следующим:

```
DELETE FROM `items` WHERE `category_id` = 1 AND `subcategory_id` LIKE %{3}%
```

Буду рад услышать новые идеи. Но ничего кроме скобочек мне в голову так и не пришло.

Comment: Другой подход - банален и описан в любом tutorial по mysql для начинающих нулевого уровня. Он настолько общеизвестен, что предлагаю попробовать найти его самостоятельно.

Comment: @klopp вот неудача:( забыл 0 уровень пройти. Сразу начал с первого когда-то. Ну а если по делу: видимо я так и не смог объясниться, чего мне надо. Поэтому лучше расскажите как обрезать строку:) Проблема в том, что по выполнению этого задания (ок купил запчасть с id = 3) ему еще надо купить 2 другие запчасти с id = 1 и id = 2. И никак не с id = 3

Comment: Что надо я как раз понял. Поэтому и предлагаю вернуться на уровень 0 и  пойти прямым путём (например, почитывая хоть какие-то туториалы - в данном случае ключевые слова "один ко многим") А не сворачивать в кривую и беспросветную тьмутаракань так рано.

Comment: @klopp ... дерзайте: ткните мне в волшебный тутореал по MySQL в котором описывалось бы то, что мне как раз нужно.

Comment: как раз в эту секунду добавил в коммент :)

Comment: @klopp да нет же... Мне отлично известен JOIN и "один ко многим", тут он без силен. Я схожу, даже перечитаю! Вдруг чего то упустил.. Но боюсь большую часть знаю наизусть. Другую часть - смотрю в доки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без "лишнего" запроса никак.

Вероятно, вам будет интересно изучить данный раздел помощи по MySQL: [String Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте функцию REPLACE. Поскольку я вижу 3 варианта: удаляемый элемент может находиться в начале строки, в конце и в середине, то написать нужно 3 реплейса.
Я бы изменил структуру таблицы. Тогда ваша проблема решалась бы просто удалением строки.

Comment: Или просто добавить в начало и конец строки разделитель - тогда можно обойтись одним REPLACE